# What's the difference between torch.mean and torch.nn.avg_pool?

Tags: pytorch

Taking a tensor with shape [4,8,12] as an example, what's the difference between the two lines:

```
torch.mean(x, dim=2)
torch.nn.functional.avg_pool1d(x, kernel_size=12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the very example you provided the result is the same, but only because you specified `dim=2` and `kernel_size` equal to the dimensionality of the third (index 2) dimension.
But in principle, you are applying two different functions, that sometimes just happen to collide with specific choices of hyperparameters.

`torch.mean` is effectively a dimensionality reduction function, meaning that when you average all values across one dimension, you effectively get rid of that dimension.
On the other hand, average 1-dimensional pooling is more powerful in this regard, as it gives you a lot more flexibility in choosing kernel size, padding and stride like you would normally do when using a convolutional layer.

You can see the first function as a specific case of 1-d pooling.